# Set Block Status from xml and show if its enabled

Tags: magento, tabs, product

Created `CMS > Block` and display it on product page as tabs following [this](http://twincreations.co.uk/add-custom-product-tab-in-magento-1-9-ce/) tutorial

**app/design/frontend/[theme]/default/layout/catalog.xml**

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.sizes" as="sizes" template="catalog/product/view/sizes.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Size Guide</value></action>
</block>
```

From the above code, block title is set from admin and it will be shown as product tab even if its disabled from admin end.

1. How can we show block only if its enabled from admin and check using
   some `IF` condition in xml ?

Also is it possible to show the title given from admin end rather than setting it from `XML` file ?

Answer (score 2):

Declare an observer of controller_action_layout_load_before event in config.xml.

```
<controller_action_layout_load_before>
  <observers>
     <namespace_module_model_observer>
        <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Observer</class>
        <method>setHandle</method>
     </namespace_module_model_observer>
  </observers>
</controller_action_layout_load_before>
```

Define observer.

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer
{
    public function setHandle(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if (!Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load('cms_block_identifier')->getIsActive()) {
            Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle('your_handle_name');
        }
    }
}
```

Add handle to layout xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <your_handle_name>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <remove name="product.sizes" />
        </reference>
    </your_handle_name>
</layout>
```